# How to implement column grouping in react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-table

I used react-table in my Application. We used Row Grouping. In the same way I want to implement Column Grouping. Expanding and Collapsing the columns by clicking the arrow button in column. Please look into the below image.Please share your thoughts.[image]